# Recursive regex for matching everything in parenthesis (PCRE)

Tags: regex, pcre

I am surprised to not easily find a similar question with an answer on SO. I would like to match everything in some functions. The idea is to remove the functions which are useless.

```
foo(some (content)) --> some (content)
```

So I am trying to match everything in the function call which can include parenthesis. Here is my PCRE regex:

```
(?<name>\w+)\s*\(\K
(?<e>
     [^()]+
     |
     [^()]*
         \((?&e)\)
     [^()]*
)*
(?=\))
```

https://regex101.com/r/gfMAIM/1

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I don't really understand why.

Comment: Is the inspected call of the function always at the start on the line or not?

Comment: @Predicate Let's assume everything is one one line, but you can find multiple function call on this line: `foo(); bar()\n`

Comment: is there a way that the parenthesis are not balanced in the desired match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Group `e` pattern does not do the right job, currently, it matches  parentheses with 1 depth level as you only recursed the `e` pattern once. It needs to match as many `(...)` substrings as there are present, and thus, the subroutine pattern needs to be inside a `*` or `+` quantified group, and it can even be "simplified" to `(?<e>[^()]*(?:\((?&e)\)[^()]*)*)`.

Note that your Group `e` pattern is equal to `(?<e>[^()]+|\((?&e)\))*`. `[^()]*` around `\((?&e)\)` are redundant since the `[^()]+` alternative will consume the chars other than `(` and `)` on the current depth level.

Also, you quantified the Group `e` pattern making it a [repeated capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) that only keeps the text matched during the last iteration.

You may use

```
(?<name>\w+)\s*\(\K(?<e>[^()]*(?:\((?&e)\)[^()]*)*)(?=\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aCKGFr/1)

**Details**

- `(?<name>\w+)\s*\(\K` - 1+ word chars, 0+ whitespaces and `(` that are omitted from the match
- `(?<e>` - start of Group `e`

  - `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

    - `\(` - a  `(` char
    - `(?&e)` - Group `e` pattern recursed
    - `\)` - a `)`
    - `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `)*` - 0 or more repetitions
- `)` - end of `e` group
- `(?=\))` - a `)` must be immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: seems the reason why the regex suggested by OP didn't work was the `*` immediately after `(?<e>` group, adding uncatpured group inside fixed [regex01](https://regex101.com/r/gfMAIM/3)

Comment: another solution more efficient to avoid backtracking is to use possessive quantifier for example `(?<name>\w+)\s*\(\K(?<e>(?:[^()]++|\((?&e)\))*)\)`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Yes, that is a bit better. Atomic group can be used, too `(?<name>\w+)\s*\(\K(?<e>(?>[^()]+|\((?&e)\))*)(?=\))`. Also, note the last `)` must be in a lookahead (well, at least that is OP logic).

Comment: guys youre [solution](https://regex101.com/r/svbhBX/1) fails on unbalanced parenthesis. The could appear in strings.

Comment: @Predicate Those cases are out of scope, they cannot be matched with recursion. They can only be handled if specific context is known on both ends of expected matches. You can't have a *universal* regex for those scenarios.

Comment: @Predicate also ";" could appear in strings and your solution also will fail, however strings can also be discarded, using backtracking verbs, something like `"(?:[^"]++|\\.*)*"(*SKIP)(?!)|`...

Answer (score 1):

The following regex does the matching without taking extra steps:

```
(?<name>\w+)\s*(\((?<e>([^()]*+|(?2))+)\))
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/sJ8TgK/1)

But that doesn't match following strings that contain unbalanced parentheses in a quoted string:

- `foo(bar = ')')`
- `foo(bar(john = "(Doe..."))`

So what you should look for is:

```
(?<name>\w+)\s*(\((?<e>([^()'"]*+|"(?>[^"\\]*+|\\.)*"|'(?>[^'\\]*+|\\.)*'|(?2))+)\))
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/sJ8TgK/2)

Regex breakdown:

- `(?<name>\w+)\s*` Match function name and trailing spaces
- `(`  Start of a cluster

  - `\(`  Match a literal `(`
  - `(?<e>`  Start of named capturing group `e`

    - `(`  Start of capturing group #2

      - `[^()'"]*+`  Match any thing except `()'"`
      - `|`  Or
      - `"(?>[^"\\]*+|\\.)*"`  Match any thing between double quotes
      - `|`  Or
      - `'(?>[^'\\]*+|\\.)*'`  Match any thing between single quotes
      - `|`  Or
      - `(?2)`  Recurse second capturing group
    - `)+`  Repeat as much as possible, at least once
  - `)`  End of capturing group
  - `\)`  Match `)` literally
- `)`  End of capturing group

Answer (score 0):

I have simple regex without [recursion](https://regex101.com/r/LeMzen/1).

```
(?<=[\w ]{2}\().*(?=\))
```

by now it deals with unbalanced perenthesis, but it does not deals with multiple functions that are on one line. It could be handeled if you know the delmiters between the function. e.g. `;` if that is Java code.

[Variant 2](https://regex101.com/r/LeMzen/6) (updated for multiple functions on a row):

```
(?<=[\w ]\()[^;\n]*(?=\))
```

[Variant 3](https://regex101.com/r/OWRTjf/5) (allowing `;` in strings):

```
(?<=[\w ]\()([^;\n]|".*?")*(?=\))
```

[Variant 4](https://regex101.com/r/OWRTjf/10) (escaping strings):

```
(?<=[\w \n]\()(?:[^;\n"]|(?:"(?:[^"]|\\")*?(?<!\\)"))*(?=\))
```

Comment: check variant 2

Comment: You could improve the first lookbehind so it not only checks the one character, but the job becomes harder because PCRE does not allows Lookbehinds with varying length. Probably more context is needed fo that. But I dont see a problem  in checking only one character before the `(`

Comment: And because `*` is greedy it will go the whole way to the last `)` and not match `;` also. Balancing problem will not occure and multiple functions on a line are allowed (if the delimiter is `;`)

Comment: Keep it short and simple ^^

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul see Variant 3

Comment: variant 3 will fail now with `f("a;");g("b");`, a fix could be  `(?<=[\w ]\()([^";\n]|"(?:[^"]++|\\.*)*"(*SKIP))*(?=\))`

Comment: Without recursions this is never going to guarantee correct matches.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Ive corrected it with laziness.)) Now it works. Check Var 3. Also youre regex fails on the last one

Comment: Guys, cmon, Really like your thoughtful rgexes, but I at least desire some likes of my code.^^ You say you cant guarantee with my code, but apparently my code solves all cases we all together created and it did faster than you codes.^^

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul conquered in Var 4. ^^

Comment: well, `f("a"){""};g("\"b;");` or just `f("a")+f("b");`

Comment: @revo as we saw in some upper regexes reccursion cannot guarantee it too.) Nevermind, i like your solutions guys, but I really like the simplicity of my regex

Comment: The forth regex fails on many right matches e.g. `bar(a =") ", b = " );")`. This is an endless patching. You have to use recursions for this. BTW, recursions CAN guarantee.